# How to use findElements in Codeception using php

Tags: php, codeception

I have a page that contains a table with number of rows.

I need to work around a logic to which I need number of rows in that table

After searching in Google I found that `findElements` would do my work. When I tried this method I got a fatal error:

```
Fatal error:

Call to a member function findElements() on a non-object webDriver->findElements(\WebDriverBy::id("table-padding"));.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just saw your question as I was looking for the same thing, I was able to do it in this way:

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function(\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver){ //Store current window id

    global $meetings;
    $meetings = $webdriver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssselector('.today'));

});
```

I hope this can help you with your project.

Comment: Thanks it's working, can you also help me to know if the $meetings is storing all fetched elements then how to perform click over each element?

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to use `$I->grabMultiple('.items', 'some_attribute')`

https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#grabMultiple

---

Another way is to use `DOMDocument`

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($I->grabPageSource());
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('.items');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$els = $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_findElements('.items');
```

_findElements

hidden API method, expected to be used from Helper classes

Locates element using available Codeception locator types:

XPath
CSS
Strict Locator

See more in [docs](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#Methods)